# UWP Prism ViewModel Is Null

Tags: uwp, prism

Using the Visual Studio 2017 Universal Windows Templates I created a test UWP App using Prism. It all works fine untill I added a new blank page to the app. The view is called:

```
AbcPage
```

The XAML

```
<Page
x:Class="UI_Test_1.Views.AbcPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="using:UI_Test_1.Views"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:prismMvvm="using:Prism.Windows.Mvvm"
prismMvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="test" />
</Grid>
```

I added the

```
 xmlns:prismMvvm="using:Prism.Windows.Mvvm"
 prismMvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
```

The code behind is thus:

```
 namespace UI_Test_1.Views
{
   public sealed partial class AbcPage : Page
   {
      AbcPageViewModel viewModel => DataContext as AbcPageViewModel;
      public AbcPage()
      {
          this.InitializeComponent();
      }
      private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
         var vm = viewModel;//this is null
       }
  }
}
```

And finally my ViewModel:

```
namespace UI_Test_1.ViewModels
{
   public class AbcPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
   {
       public AbcPageViewModel()
       {
       //never called
        }
    }
 }
```

The conventions appear to be correct or have I made a mistake? Why is the

```
 AbcViewModel
```

null? How do I debug this?

Comment: You need to add your AbcPageViewModel in ViewModels folder, that's where prism will try to search by default.

Comment: The AbcPageViewModel is in the ViewModels folder.

Comment: Which prism version you that you used?

Comment: Alas there is no code such as that in my project. App.xaml.cs has initialisation routines and you can configure containers for Ioc but nothing like the link.Thanks.

Comment: So, emm, the issue solved?

Comment: I used the template that comes with Visual Studio 15.8.9 Prism Unity 7.1.0.431 according ti Nuget

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183681/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-paul-stanley).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake with the naming conventions. If your page is AbcPage then the viewmodel should be AbcViewModel NOT AbcPageViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

For using prism early releases within uwp, you need config more ting base on native uwp project, such as `App` class and `Page` class.  Certainly, the official has provide [code sample](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Windows/tree/master/SplitViewSample/SplitViewSample) you could refer.

```
public sealed partial class App : PrismUnityApplication
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override UIElement CreateShell(Frame rootFrame)
    {
        var shell = Container.Resolve<AppShell>();
        shell.SetContentFrame(rootFrame);
        return shell;
    }

    protected override Task OnInitializeAsync(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Container.RegisterInstance<IResourceLoader>(new ResourceLoaderAdapter(new ResourceLoader()));
        return base.OnInitializeAsync(args);
    }

    protected override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(PageTokens.Main.ToString(), null);
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

For last 7.2 version that does not release has new usage mode. For more please check this [link](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Source/Windows10).

```
sealed partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    public static IPlatformNavigationService NavigationService { get; private set; }

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry container)
    {
        container.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>(nameof(Views.MainPage));
    }

    public override void OnInitialized()
    {
        NavigationService = Prism.Navigation.NavigationService
            .Create(new Frame(), Gestures.Back, Gestures.Forward, Gestures.Refresh);
        NavigationService.SetAsWindowContent(Window.Current, true);
    }

    public override void OnStart(StartArgs args)
    {
        NavigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(Views.MainPage));
    }
}
```